# WAMP Site Links Go To Site Index

Tags: joomla, indexing, wamp

I opened up a Joomla/Localhost WAMP site that I was working on, and when I tried to go to my Joomla login page, it took me to a site index. I tried my other links and websites, and it did the same thing. Refreshed the Cache (another post recommended), tried a different browser, but nothing. If I can avoid a fresh install, it would be preferred (of course), so I wanted to get y'alls insight first.

Comment: What colour is the wampmanager icon?  What version of WAMPServer?  What has changed since you last opened this site?  What url are you using?  Where you clicking the WAMPServer homepage links to get to your site?  Do the standard `phpMyAdmin` and `phpinfo()` links work on the homepage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Color:Green, Version:2.5, Changes: Nothing That I'm Aware Of :/ the computer remained on, I only rebooted it after the issue occurred, urls: file:///C:/wamp/www/MintAndHoney/administrator and also file:///C:/wamp/www/mintandhoney2/installation (for a fresh install) Both show index. phpMyAdmin and phpinfo(): Are Working Correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there is your problem, you are double clicking on Windows Explorer to launch your site. **Thats wrong**

If you do that the site is not actually run through Apache and therefore cannot be passed through the PHP interpreter, so your PHP code never gets run.

Enter the url directly into the browser address bar as

```
localhost/mintandhoney2
and 
localhost/mintandhoney
```

Its actually A MUCH, MUCH better idea to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects, especially if they are CMS's like Joomla and WordPress, specifically if you want to eventually copy them to a live hosted site, or copy a live site to your localhost environment.

Here is a link to an answer that describes how to do that and also why it is a VERY GOOD idea.

[WAMPServer and why its a good idea to create Virtual Hosts for ALL your projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)